# Running S3-put-triggered Lambda function on existing S3 objects?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I have a Lambda function in Node.js that processes new images added to my bucket. I want to run the function for all existing objects. How can I do this? I figured the easiest way is to "re-put" each object, to trigger the function, but I'm not sure how to do this.

To be clear - I want to run, one-time, on each of the *existing* objects. The trigger is already working for *new* objects, I just need to run it on the objects that were inserted *before* the lambda function was created.

Comment: Please, let me understand correctly your requirement, exactly what you need is that everytime that you add an image to your bucket you want to reprocess ALL the existing images? or how many times do you want to process each image?

Comment: @TachúSalamanca Updated the OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following Lambda function will do what you require.

It will iterate through each file in your target S3 bucket and for each it will execute the desired lambda function against it emulating a put operation.

You're probably going to want to put a very long execution time allowance against this function

```
var TARGET_BUCKET="my-bucket-goes-here";
var TARGET_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME="TestFunct";
var S3_PUT_SIMULATION_PARAMS={
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "s3": {
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "object": {
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901",
          "key": "HappyFace.jpg",
          "size": 1024
        },
        "bucket": {
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
          "name": "sourcebucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          }
        },
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH",
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789"
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:s3"
    }
  ]
};

var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3();
var lambda = new aws.Lambda();


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    retrieveS3BucketContents(TARGET_BUCKET, function(s3Objects){
        simulateS3PutOperation(TARGET_BUCKET, s3Objects, simulateS3PutOperation, function(){ 
            console.log("complete."); 
        });
    });
};

function retrieveS3BucketContents(bucket, callback){
    s3.listObjectsV2({
        Bucket: TARGET_BUCKET
    }, function(err, data) {
        callback(data.Contents);
    });
}

function simulateS3PutOperation(bucket, s3ObjectStack, callback, callbackEmpty){
    var params = {
      FunctionName: TARGET_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME, 
      Payload: ""
    };

    if(s3ObjectStack.length > 0){
        var s3Obj = s3ObjectStack.pop();
        var p = S3_PUT_SIMULATION_PARAMS;
        p.Records[0].s3.bucket.name = bucket;
        p.Records[0].s3.object.key = s3Obj.Key;
        params.Payload = JSON.stringify(p, null, 2);
        lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          else{
              callback(bucket, s3ObjectStack, callback, callbackEmpty);
          }
        });
    }
    else{
        callbackEmpty();   
    }
}
```

Below is the full policy that your lambda query will need to execute this method, it allows R/W to CloudWatch logs and ListObject access to S3. You need to fill in your bucket details where you see MY-BUCKET-GOES-HERE

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1477382207000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-GOES-HERE/*"
            ]
        },
        {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of, thank you! Ps. your website is down.

Comment: Thanks Rothschild! I had no idea :) Cheers!

Comment: Hey Xavier, I'm getting access denied with this, with no further explanation. What kind of role policy do I need? I'm a heroku guy so apologies but lambda is too good to pass up.

Comment: I have a lambda basic execution policy, which got rid of the lambda execution permission error, but now I just get access denied. Changed the bucket, function name, and the region in the JSON.

Comment: You will need to grant read permissions to s3 to the IAM role that lambda is executing as

Comment: Do you need to include all of the variables in your `S3_PUT_SIMULATION_PARAMS` object? For example, do you actually need to include the object eTag, sequencer, and size? It looks like the only things you're editing are the bucket name, and object key? Does everything else even need to be present in the payload? The bucket ARN doesn't even seem to be checked.

Comment: Never mind. I've just realized that it's literally just giving your function an event object. So I guess you give as much as the function needs.

Answer (score 4):

This thread helped push me in the right direction as I needed to invoke a lambda function per file for an existing 50k files in two buckets. I decided to write it in *python* and **limit the amount of lambda functions running simultaneously to 500** (the concurrency limit for many aws regions is 1000).

The script creates a worker pool of 500 threads who feed off a queue of bucket keys. Each worker waits for their lambda to be finished before picking up another. Since the execution of this script against my 50k files will take a couple hours, I'm just running it off my local machine. Hope this helps someone!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Proper imports
import json
import time
import base64
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from argh import dispatch_command

import boto3
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

client = boto3.client('lambda')

def invoke_lambdas():
    try:
        # replace these with your access keys
        s3 = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
        buckets = [s3.get_bucket('bucket-one'), s3.get_bucket('bucket-two')]

        queue = Queue()
        num_threads = 500

        # create a worker pool
        for i in range(num_threads):
            worker = Thread(target=invoke, args=(queue,))
            worker.setDaemon(True)
            worker.start()

        for bucket in buckets:
            for key in bucket.list():
                queue.put((bucket.name, key.key))

        queue.join()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def invoke(queue):
    while True:
        bucket_key = queue.get()

        try:
            print('Invoking lambda with bucket %s key %s. Remaining to process: %d'
                % (bucket_key[0], bucket_key[1], queue.qsize()))
            trigger_event = {
                'Records': [{
                    's3': {
                        'bucket': {
                            'name': bucket_key[0]
                        },
                        'object': {
                            'key': bucket_key[1]
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }

            # replace lambda_function_name with the actual name
            # InvocationType='RequestResponse' means it will wait until the lambda fn is complete
            response = client.invoke(
                FunctionName='lambda_function_name',
                InvocationType='RequestResponse',
                LogType='None',
                ClientContext=base64.b64encode(json.dumps({}).encode()).decode(),
                Payload=json.dumps(trigger_event).encode()
            )
            if response['StatusCode'] != 200:
                print(response)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('Exception during invoke_lambda')

        queue.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dispatch_command(invoke_lambdas)
```

Answer (score 2):

As I had to do this on a **very large** bucket, and lambda functions have a max. execution time of 10 minutes, I ended up doing a script with the Ruby AWS-SDK.

```
require 'aws-sdk-v1'

class LambdaS3Invoker

  BUCKET_NAME = "HERE_YOUR_BUCKET"
  FUNCTION_NAME = "HERE_YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME"
  AWS_KEY = "HERE_YOUR_AWS_KEY"
  AWS_SECRET = "HERE_YOUR_AWS_SECRET"
  REGION = "HERE_YOUR_REGION"

  def execute
    bucket.objects({ prefix: 'products'}).each do |o|
      lambda_invoke(o.key)
    end
  end

  private

  def lambda_invoke(key)
    lambda.invoke({
      function_name: FUNCTION_NAME,
      invocation_type: 'Event',
      payload: JSON.generate({
        Records: [{
          s3: {
            object: {
              key: key,
            },
            bucket: {
              name: BUCKET_NAME,
            }
          }
        }]
      })
    })
  end

  def lambda
    @lambda ||= Aws::Lambda::Client.new(
      region: REGION,
      access_key_id: AWS_KEY,
      secret_access_key: AWS_SECRET
    )
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= Aws::S3::Resource.new(
      access_key_id: AWS_KEY,
      secret_access_key: AWS_SECRET
    )
  end

  def bucket
    @bucket ||= resource.bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
  end
end
```

And then you can call it like:

```
LambdaS3Invoker.new.execute
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a one time script which uses AWS SDK to invoke your lambda function. This solution doesn't require you to "re-put" the object.

I am going to base my answer on AWS JS SDK.

> To be clear - I want to run, one-time, on each of the existing
>   objects. The trigger is already working for new objects, I just need
>   to run it on the objects that were inserted before the lambda function
>   was created.

As you have a working lambda function which accepts S3 put events what you need to do is find all the unprocessed object in S3 (If you have DB entries for each S3 object the above should be easy if not then you might find the S3 list  object function handy http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property).

Then for each unprocessed S3 object obtained create a JSON object which looks like S3 Put Event Message(shown below) and call the Lambda invoke function with the above JSON object as payload.

You can find the lambda invoke function docs at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

When creating the fake S3 Put Event Message Object for your lambda function you can ignore most of the actual object properties **depending on your lambda function**. I guess the least you will have to set is bucket name and object key.

S3 Put Event Message Structure http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html

```
{  
   "Records":[  
      {  
         "eventVersion":"2.0",
         "eventSource":"aws:s3",
         "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
         "eventTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
         "eventName":"ObjectCreated:Put",
         "userIdentity":{  
            "principalId":"AIDAJDPLRKLG7UEXAMPLE"
         },
         "requestParameters":{  
            "sourceIPAddress":"127.0.0.1"
         },
         "responseElements":{  
            "x-amz-request-id":"C3D13FE58DE4C810",
            "x-amz-id-2":"FMyUVURIY8/IgAtTv8xRjskZQpcIZ9KG4V5Wp6S7S/JRWeUWerMUE5JgHvANOjpD"
         },
         "s3":{  
            "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
            "configurationId":"testConfigRule",
            "bucket":{  
               "name":"mybucket",
               "ownerIdentity":{  
                  "principalId":"A3NL1KOZZKExample"
               },
               "arn":"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            },
            "object":{  
               "key":"HappyFace.jpg",
               "size":1024,
               "eTag":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
               "versionId":"096fKKXTRTtl3on89fVO.nfljtsv6qko",
               "sequencer":"0055AED6DCD90281E5"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to go to S3 in AWS console and edit Metadata and save
[image]

Answer (score -2):

well basically what you need is to use some api calls(boto for example if you use python)and list all new objects or all objects in your s3 bucket and then process these objects

here is a snippet:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = S3Connection()
source = conn.get_bucket(src_bucket)
src_list = set([key.name for key in source.get_all_keys(headers=None, prefix=prefix)])
//and then you can go over this src list
for entry in src_list:
   do something
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question exactly. The bit I'm stuck with is running the Lambda function on the objects. It seems to only run with a trigger, i.e. inserting the objects. Is it possible to get all the objects, and then call the lambda function on each of them? I'm using Node, by the way.

Comment: To clarify, the function converts an image into various sizes. There are already photos in the bucket from before I implemented the feature, and I need to run it on these objects.

Comment: so you want to trigger the function on inserting objects and then run it on all objects in the bucket?

Comment: Currently I have an S3 trigger set up, and that works for new objects, as it's triggered by a put call. All is well for new objects. However, the objects already in there obviously don't trigger the put as they're _already_ in the bucket. I want to run the function / trigger it on these objects. In my head, the cleanest approach seems to be to just reinsert the objects with the exact same name, or "reput" them, in order to trigger, but I'm relatively junior and I'm not sure if this is unnecessary.

Comment: you can do it either 2 ways here trigger a function which checks for the unconverted images and then adds those images to the list/queue which will convert the pictures. or invoke lambda test and configure a test event for manual invoking which will force converting manually