# Is it possible to run a lambda against an existing aws s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We have lots of images uploaded to an existing bucket.

Then we have implemented the lambda thumbnail functionality > bucket creation and bulk image upload.

Does anyone know if we can run those against an existing bucket or is this only for newly uploaded images?

Comment: Side-comment: Instead of creating the thumbnails yourself, you could use a resize-as-a-service offering such as [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) and [Imgix](http://imgix.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Lambda event triggers only for newly uploaded images.

Comment: This is correct, but there's a workaround.  Object metadata is immutable, so "editing" object metadata requires copying the object onto itself... which in turn means that modifying object metadata is a way to trigger the Lambda function for existing objects.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot good call.. I found this on a quick search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003827/running-s3-put-triggered-lambda-function-on-existing-s3-objects